# Updating tables between different SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server databases (A and B), and they are running on separate machines. In order to make A same as B, I used to backup B, copy the backup to A machine and restore it as A database.

A problem was that restoring updates all tables in A database. What I want to was update specific tables in A database with those in B database. What can I do? Here are more information:

- A database is live production so that I cannot set it single user mode.
- The specific tables in A database are being read by web servers. They are neither being updated nor changed.

Simply speaking, I want to update specific tables in live database without letting web users blocking.

Comment: Offtopic. not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. The best guess is you would want to restore to DatabaseC, then write some sql to do the updates or whatever to DatabaseA.

Comment: Read about transactional replication.

Comment: Have you considered transactional replication?

Comment: See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo and http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2

Comment: Oh, sorry about asking it in a wrong section. Thanks guys, I will try Transaction Replication. Aaron, thanks for the links!